# Application interfaces are blurry while the chrome and window are clear

Tags: windows, resolution, anti-aliasing

In some applications, the elements are really blurry. The first time I noticed it was when I was watching a YouTube video a few weeks ago, the browser (I've tried with Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome, same results) looks normal, but the video player itself is really blurry. Not the video, only the player options (pause, play, volume, etc.). I could still see what the buttons said, so I didn't worry too much about it as I thought it'd go away by itself.

Recently I tried to install a Java + netbeans bundle, and as soon as I ran the install, this showed up:

[image: java installer dialog]

I left the install running in the background for about 20 mins (by accident, I was going to close it but I forgot), and then it restored how it's supposed to look.

Video card is ATI Radeon 6950 2GB.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I managed to figure it out by myself.

I checked the video card settings (for the 1000th time), and under "Anti aliasing" i saw an option labelled "Morphological filtering". I googled it and found a few other threads about it on other sites, so i tried turning it off, and voila! It works now.